# I need to make my sentence sound like slang

Tags: american-english, slang

I have a line "Turn on your iPod. We're about to get on the road." (Guy is  talking with his passenger in a car), so I need to make it more like slang, maybe a bit rough. The point is that the other guy is not native English speaking, so he shouldn't understand that line.

Comment: Not clear what you’re asking. You want to rephrase that line to sound more “rough” and slangy? Have you come up with anything so far?

Comment: @Mixolydian Yes, exactly. I thought about something like "Fire up your noise, we're get going" but I'm not sure since I'm not native one either, so that's why I need some help

Comment: You might have better luck with this sort of question over on [writers.se], as it's really looking for writing advice, and is not really a question about learning English.  (That said, perhaps something like "Fire up your tunes, we're rolling out.")

Comment: @Hellion Thank you for your advice and for the link!

Comment: Driver: It's 106 miles to [wherever], we got a full tank of gas, an iPod full of tunes, half a pack of cigarettes, it's dark and we're wearing sunglasses. Passenger: Hit it.

Comment: The real problem is that slang changes very quickly. You would have to decide (a) when the action takes place and (b) how old the person speaking is. This is because different generations speak differently. A teenager would think their parents' slang was laughable not to say embarrassing. It also depends what country and what part of that country they live in. Also what class they are. If you take this question to the Writing site, you should tell them all these factors, *When, Where, Who.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make the line sound more casual, I'd suggest something like: "Let's crank some tunes! It's time to hit the road."

**"Let's crank some tunes"** implies that both passengers want to hear the music. That should be enough to make it slangy, unless the person with the iPod is wearing headphones, then a different phrase would most likely be used.

Comment: Yes, actually, the person with the iPod is going to listen with his headphones, I didn't even think that it could be important! P.S. But thank you, I would definitely remember "Let's crank some tunes", never heard that before